# Grails: create rest api with plugin jaxrs and protect resource with spring security oauth?

Tags: grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jax-rs

I have used the plugin jaxrs to create rest api (http://grails.org/plugin/jaxrs) and implemented Oauth 2 with http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth2-provider.

Now I want to protect resource which created by the plugin jaxrs. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thanks,

Long Do

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should use the annotation @Secured provided by spring security in your rest controllers or methods

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

@Secured(['YOUR_ROLE'])
```

Comment: resources are in grails-app/resources, not controllers. I used @Secured but it didn't work. Now I am using filters to protect them. Thanks for your reply.